# commandButton only works on the second click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

Hi i had a button but it only reacts  on the second click on it.
I use jsf 2.2 and primefaces 4.0

```
<p:commandButton style="width:350px" type="submit" action="#{regiBean.register}"
        value="#{msg['regi_title']}" ajax="false" update="regiForm">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: The code you posted is not enough for reproducing the problem.

Comment: ok i post the whole page in a dropbox link

Comment: here is the code of the whole site https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcwtpoi8hn5a6uw/reg.txt